# ffmpeg fade effect loses quality of video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the following code to add a fade in effect to audio/video, however the resulting output quality is really poor:

```
 ffmpeg -i in.ts -filter_complex  "[0:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=3[v]; [0:a]afade=t=in:st=0:d=3[a]"  -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.ts
```

Any suggestions on improving the quality of the output?

Comment: Set a bitrate or crf value.

Comment: What output video format do you want? Default encoder for .ts is mpeg2video which outputs an older video format. Or do you want something more modern like H.264 video?

Comment: @llogan yes, H.264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use a better encoder

Add the `-c:v libx264` output option. This will use the encoder libx264 to output H.264 video instead of the encoder mpeg2video which outputs MPEG-2 video and is the default encoder for .ts outputs.

MPEG-2 video is an old format and the default bitrate used by mpeg2video is no longer sufficient for typical modern inputs. If you want MPEG-2 video then use the `-b:v` option to set the bitrate, or use the `-q:v` option (range is 2-31) to roughly set the quality. These options are mutually exclusive, so only use one or the other.

## Adjust the libx264 rate control method

If you don't like the default quality of libx264 you can adjust it with the `-crf` option. Range is 0-51. 0 is lossless. 18 or so is visually lossless. 23 is default. 51 is worst quality.

Or if you want ABR use `-b:v` and choose a value in bits, such as `-b:v 4000k`.

These options are mutually exclusive, so only use one or the other. You didn't provide any requirements or other info, so I'll guess that you should use `-crf`.

For more info see [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue while working with audio files. For me the best option is to convert audio files first to lossless .wav, do all things that I need to do and then covert them back to .mp3 or other lossy formats. This is the way that is used in audio editing apps and the most gentle way to work with audio or video files

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].